# Why would Linux be killing my process?

Tags: linux, rhel, process

- Redhat Linux Enterprise Server 5.10 (I know it's old, I can't change that)
- This machine is virtualized using VMTools.
- Total memory for this VM: 32GB. Total disk swap space (virtual memory): 36GB. 900GB left on main drive.
- Terminal is Hummingbird Exceed v14 on Windows 7. (I can't change either of these.)
- I'm not a real sysadmin, I just program on the machine. So more detailed instructions would be helpful, like where the logs are and what to grep for.

When I'm running a certain program reading 7000 lines from a spreadsheet (which is not that big), sometimes my process will just be killed and the terminal disappears.

- What are some reasons the OS might kill my process?
- The physical server this VM resides on was really busy yesterday, who knows how much memory the other VMs on this server were using, but shouldn't my 32GB of memory be reserved just for my VM?
- Would VMTOOLS look at all virtual machines when memory gets low and pick random VMs and random resource hogs to kill? (My process was using 95-99% of CPU time, but again, I thought that was just for my VM.)

Thanks. I'm really stuck here.

---

EDIT 1: I checked /var/log/syslog and ignored several types of lines using `grep -v` and what I saw that when I was kicked off, each time it looks like some resource-greedy cron jobs were running. I think that is what happened.

Now my question is, now can I limit the memory and swap space these cron jobs use, so the memory is not used up and  my terminal doesn't get killed? Is there something I can do at the OS level?

---

EDIT 12/7/2017: After further investigation with `top`, we are nowhere close to using up memory, swap space, or hard drive space. So something else is going on, and IT is looking into it.

Comment: Do you see OOM (out-of-memory) messages in the logs?

Comment: Could be that the process reached a limit set with ulimit.

Comment: Which process is "my process"?  The host process providing the X server or terminal emulator?  The guest process reading from the spreadsheet?

Comment: 1) Which logs should I check for OOM? 2) I'll read the ulimit man page to see what's up with that. 3) I am assuming the process running on the virtual machine/server. My process that was killed was assumed to be a perl process. Program works most of the time but sometimes the terminal that is running perl is killed along with perl.

Comment: So you are asking why the operating system killed your process and what to do about it, without determining what process was actually killed in the first place.  You say that the "terminal disappears", but then you say that some _other_ process, not the terminal emulator process, is the one being killed.  I suggest _before_ asking for what to do, that you determine _what actually is happening in the first place_, by looking to see what of your processes are still running and what processes are not, on host and guest.

Comment: The typical reason for a kernel to close your application is that you do not have enough memory. A complicated subsystem called oom-killer will then choose which process to kill, often the last one grabbing too much RAM but not always. In all cases your system logfiles should give you more explanations, have a look at `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/syslog` or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is, now can I limit the memory and swap space these cron jobs use, so the memory is not used up and my terminal doesn't get killed? Is there something I can do at the OS level?

Yes. Read carefully [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html). You want to use the [`ulimit`  bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) appropriately.

Be aware of [memory overcommitment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_overcommitment).